# Redux-persist v5 saves some parts of state but not others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

So I am using React Native with redux and redux-persist and storing my data using AsyncStorage. My store looks like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "./reducers";
import autoMergeLevel2 from "redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
  blacklist: ["prices"]
};

const persistentReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export const store = createStore(
  persistentReducer,
  {},
  applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

My reducers look like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import AuthReducer from "./AuthReducer";
import PriceReducers from "./PriceReducers";
import SearchReducers from "./SearchReducers";
import SetPriceReducers from "./SetPriceReducers";
import GetCatalogReducers from "./GetCatalogReducers";

export default combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
  prices: PriceReducers,
  search: SearchReducers,
  setPrice: SetPriceReducers,
  catalog: GetCatalogReducers
});
```

And my App.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store, persistor } from "./src/store";
import Router from "./src/Router";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/lib/integration/react";
import { Loading } from "./src/components/common";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(store.getState().catalog);
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate loading={<Loading />} persistor={persistor}>
            <Router />
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
.....
```

And finally, here is my "catalog" reducer:

```
import { GET_CATALOG } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CATALOG:
      console.log("reducer", action.payload);
      return { ...action.payload };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};
```

The main issue is that my "auth" state gets persisted but but the other parts of state (excluding the blacklisted "prices") are not persisted. 
I know that my state contains the information because I can `console.log(store.getState().catalog)` 
and see all the data, but for some reason, when I refresh the app, the "catalog" portion of state is empty. And all the while my "auth" portion functions perfectly.

Any ideas what might be causing some parts of my state to persist and not others?

This article (https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/the-definitive-guide-to-redux-persist-84738167975)  along with the redux-persist docs was what I used to set up redux-persist.

Comment: are you rehydrating your auth reducer? or has that changed since I used redux-persist?

Comment: I believe that with redux-persist v5, explicitly rehydrating is no longer necessary unless you need to customize the way in which the state is rehydrated and this is done through transforms.